# Application design to handle dynamically pivoted data

Tags: database-design

I have an application that has different granularity for each record type.
Assume that inventory type A is planned quarterly, so it has 4 values, and inventory type B is planned monthly, so it has 12 values.
Assume that monthly is the lowest time horizon, so the table has max of 12 values.
From UI perspective, the UI needs to display the record in pivoted way. Meaning to say if system is displaying inventory type A, it will display something like

```
Inventory Type | Time       | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4
A              | Quarterly  | 100     | 200     | 300     | 400
```

So here value 1 represents value of Q1, value 2 represents value of Q2, and so on.

When it displays inventory type B, it will display something like

```
Inventory Type | Time      | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 | Value 7 | Value 8 | Value 9 | Value 10 | Value 11 | Value 12
B              | Monthly   | 1       | 2       | 3       | 4       | 5       | 6       | 7       | 8       | 9       | 10       | 11       | 12
```

So here value 1 represents value of month January, value 2 represents value of month February, and so on.

User can go and edit the values on the UI and save back to the database.

I am thinking between 2 designs of the database.

## Design 1

Create parent-child table:

```
Parent table

ID | Inventory Type | Time
1  | A              | Quarterly
2  | B              | Monthly

Child table

Child ID | Parent ID | Value Name    | Value
1        | 1         | Value 1       | 100
2        | 1         | Value 2       | 200
3        | 1         | Value 3       | 300
4        | 1         | Value 4       | 400
5        | 2         | Value 1       | 1 
6        | 2         | Value 2       | 2
7        | 2         | Value 3       | 3
8        | 2         | Value 4       | 4
9        | 2         | Value 5       | 5
10       | 2         | Value 6       | 6
11       | 2         | Value 7       | 7
12       | 2         | Value 8       | 8
13       | 2         | Value 9       | 9
14       | 2         | Value 10      | 10
15       | 2         | Value 11      | 11
16       | 2         | Value 12      | 12
```

Using this approach, when reading the data, I will need to do some pivoting so that it can be displayed on the UI. Similarly, when saving the data, I will need to unpivot the data and create / update the child record accordingly. So the process is a bit heavy on the backend to convert between pivot/unpivot, but the storage is more efficient.

## Design 2

Given that the maximum number of values are 12, create only one table

```
ID | Inventory Type | Time        | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 | Value 4 | Value 5 | Value 6 | Value 7 | Value 8 | Value 9 | Value 10 | Value 11 | Value 12
1  | A              | Quarterly   | 100     | 200     | 300     | 400     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL     | NULL     | NULL    
2  | B              | Monthly     | 1       | 2       | 3       | 4       | 5       | 6       | 7       | 8       | 9       | 10       | 11       | 12
```

Reading and saving the data is quite straightforward, no need to pivot and unpivot, but storage is not efficient (looking at inventory type A, Value 5 to 12 are always NULL). Performance should be faster as there are less processing.

Which is the better approach to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 1):

"Better" depends on many factors. Since you don't list all of them, it's impossible to tell which is better. You've already listed some pros and cons (although your storage argument is likely moot as most databases have very efficient ways of dealing with NULL columns.)

Instead of focusing on some probably irrelevant optimization, you should focus on the semantics of this data model. What do these properties represent? Can you give them meaningful names? Why are both record types stored in the same table? What are their commonalities and/or differences? If you get your data model right, you may gain a better understanding of how to implement it best. Maybe it's easiest to have two different tables? Maybe just having NULL values isn't elegant but provides best performance? Maybe a separate table for records of type B that just holds the values of properties 3 and 4 (although that's unlikely to provide better behavior than the NULL columns)?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question to provide more context. Both records are stored in the same table because it's the same item. Assume it like inventory A. Inventory A is planned in quarterly basis, and inventory B is planned in monthly basis, since both of them are about inventory, they are stored in the same table, even though the planning for both of them are on different time horizon. Everything is the same, the difference is only on the time horizon (quarterly vs monthly).

Comment: This indicates that the data model should actually have one row per time interval, matching your first approach. Entries for the quarterly inventory plan would have "Value Name" of 2022-Q1, 2022-Q2, 2022-Q3, 2022-Q4, while a monthly inventory plan would have 2022-01, 2022-02, etc. You could also instead have columns `year`, `start_month`, `duration` which would make database operations easier, for example when you want to calculate average monthly inventory for a quarterly plan using database mechanisms. You should avoid using one column with different semantics depending on the context.